# ¿Cómo pasar filas desde un datagridview(que no está conectado a una base de datos) a otro datagridview que sí está conectado a una base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Cómo paso filas desde un datagridview que no está conectado a una base de datos a otro datagridview que sí está conectado a una base de datos SQL SERVER y viceversa en c#?

Comment: Una clase y `DataGridView.DataSource = new List<MiClase>();` no funciona? Te invito a pasarte por [el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/Tour) para que aprendas mejor como funciona la comunidad! Y agradeceriamos que editaras la pregunta para agregar lo que intentaste hasta el momento

Answer (score 1):

Podrías recorrer las filas del primer `GridView` y castearlas a un objeto (el del otro `GridView`)... al final agrégalos todos a una lista de ese tipo de objeto y únicamente asigna al `GridView` que sí está conectado.